# Run a series of PowerShell Tasks on AWS Serverless for more than 1 hour

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

We are using a task-scheduler to run a series (sequence) of tasks/jobs (*SOAP calls*) no our site, every night. But, we want to use AWS services such as **Step-Function and Lambda** to achieve above requirement, as Task-scheduler seems less reliable.

Challenge with Lambda is, **15 min. max timeout**. As some of our jobs take more than **1 hour** to process, I am having trouble figuring out which service could suffice the request.

I am also looking into AWS Fargate, as an alternative.

Any suggestions/edits are welcome, on which AWS services I could use to run jobs which take up to 1 hour or more.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) which is meant for long running jobs. You can use store your powershell scripts in a Docker container and schedule them to run. They will run until completion.